# Countif function not counting word with an apostrophe

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I’ve looked through the forum, but haven’t found a solution.  I’ve got some survey responses in a table like so:
It’s okay
I don't like school
It’s okay
Good, I like it

I’m using a countif function to count the number of times each response was received in the survey. The thing is my function works well with these values:
I don’t like school
Good, I like it
but my function does not pick up the phrase
It’s okay

As I’m using named ranges, the formula I am using is:

=COUNTIF(Question,"It's okay")

Please see this shared link for the example file and check out sheet 2 for the actual formula.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e1ccJh3TDeOsIrcn0f5ewQ3M6xOuBrfKBqqJ3mzXfV0

Initially, I thought the issue was that the countif function wasn’t working because of the apostrophe in the word “it’s okay”. As you can see from my example, there are other words with apostrophes in them that get counted so I’m baffled as to why this function is not working for the phrase “it’s okay”.

Has anyone seen this problem before, or any ideas as to how I could accomplish the same thing using another process?

I’ve also tried to escape the apostrophe like so :

=COUNTIF(Question,"It''s okay")

=COUNTIF(Question,"It\'s okay")

But neither case made any difference.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have different apostrophes in data and in formula:

```
’ ("Right single quotation mark", ASCII code 146) in data
' ("Single quote", ASCII code 39) in formula
```